# Asp.net deployment issue(New code does not reflect after deployment)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

We are using IIS 7. 
I have done deployment(ASP.NET Website) recently with some of the label changes in many aspx pages, some of the aspx.cs and AppCode.Cs file.

After my new deployment my latest code does not reflect, instead my previous code is showing still(without label change).

I googled many forums is saying needs to delete some dll from bin folder, but I'm not sure which one should I delete and based on what category.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: (Backup first), if your app consists of a single ASP.NET project, just remove everything except the web.config, and deploy the publish result of your app.

Comment: Did you copy over `PrecompiledApp.config` file?

Comment: Also, did you copy over all the aspx, ascx and asmx files? Also did you copy over all the  dll files?

Comment: Typically in a website, you have to copy everything except static content like images or html pages on each deployment since the dynamic content is linked to the build number of dll files.

Comment: Thanks. I have deleted all folders in existing one and pasted new published one. I could see App_Web _xxxxxxxx.dll(Application extension file) inside bin folder under newly published copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the files from bin folder and deploy it again